# Seaborn relplot subplots axis limit

Tags: python, seaborn

This is my first question on Stackoverflow!

I have been plotting some scatter plots with seaborn `relplot()`. For my first two graphs, the subplots' size and their x axis look normal. However in my third plot, I got something like this

[image]

where you can see the x-axis has only 2 ticks from 0-1, which I wanted to make them the same as the y-axis. Here is my code:

```
#Setting style
sns.set_style('ticks')
sns.set_palette('RdBu',6)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

#Plotting
rel = sns.relplot(data=df_scenarios, x="feb_pred", 
                  y="mar_pred", col="scenarios", col_wrap=2, 
                  kind="scatter", hue="pred_diff")

#Customizing
rel.set(xlabel="202002 pred", ylabel = "202003 pred")

a0 = rel.fig.axes[0]
a0.set_title("scen1")
a0.plot([0,1],[0,1],'black',linewidth = 2 )
a1 = rel.fig.axes[1]
a1.set_title("scen2")
a1.plot([0,1],[0,1],'black',linewidth = 2 )
a2 = rel.fig.axes[2]
a2.set_title("scen3")
a2.plot([0,1],[0,1],'black',linewidth = 2 )
a3 = rel.fig.axes[3]
a3.set_title("scen4")
a3.plot([0,1],[0,1],'black',linewidth = 2 )
a4 = rel.fig.axes[4]
a4.set_title("scen5")
a4.plot([0,1],[0,1],'black',linewidth = 2 )
a5 = rel.fig.axes[5]
a5.set_title("scen6")
a5.plot([0,1],[0,1],'black',linewidth = 2 )

plt.show()
```

Does anyone know what I can change in order to have the same ticks for the x and y axis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! You can add this to your plot customization to force the x limits to be equal to the y limits and make each subplot quadratic:

```py
for ax in rel.fig.axes:
    ax.set_xlim(ax.get_ylim())
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

You may also want to change the figure size to accomodate the 2x3 format.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed the x limit is now matching but the "length" of the x-axis is still remain short. I tried `rel.set(xticks = np.arange(0,1,0.2))` but it also doesn't change its length.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback. I updated my answer.